# terminology help. What should I call this sub-collection?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

Let $I:=(0,1)$ be given. I want to introduce a collection $S$ of $I$ such that the element of $S$ is the subset of $I$. For example, $S$ could be 
$$
S=\{\{0\},\,\,(0,1/2), \{3/4\}\}
$$ 
That is, the element of $S$ could be intervals or points.

Then I want to define $\mathcal S$ as the collection of all possible $S$.

I am wondering is there an existing terminology of $S$ and $\mathcal S$ as I described above? If yes, please tell me the reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are restricting yourself to intervals and points **only**, you could write
$$
\mathcal{S} = \mathcal{P}(X)
\text{ where }X = \{ x \subset I \colon x \text{ is either an interval or a singleton}\}.
$$

If instead $S$ is **any** subset of $I$, $\mathcal{S}$ is the powerset of the powerset of $I$. Some write this $\mathcal{S}=2^{2^I}$.